# Redirect subdomain of wordpress admin using .htaccess with query strings

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have been browsing the internet and haven't been able to find a solution to this, so any help would be much appreciated.

**Scenario**

I would like to redirect my subdomain file with query strings by appending another query string. For example:

```
https://sub.domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?foo=bar&key=value
```

to

```
https://sub.domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?foo=bar&key=value&new=string
```

**Attempts**

I need to add this redirect rule in .htaccess. I have tried QSA append but to no avail:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=value
    RewriteRule ^admin\.php$ /admin.php?new=string [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

What do you think the solution is?

Comment: You need the `R` flag if you want a **R**edirect. What you have a above is an _internal rewrite_, which is likely to conflict with the WordPress routing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Do I need to reformat the `rewrite rule` then, into something like
`RewriteRule ^admin\.php$ /admin.php?foo=bar&key=value&new=string [R=301,L]`
?

Comment: Also, where is this `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: It is within the subdomain, so like: root/public_html/sub/.htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing rule is an *internal rewrite*. To make this into a redirect, you just need to add the `R` flag. However, you also appear to be missing the `/wp-admin` path segment in the URL?

So, try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=value
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^new=string
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/admin\.php$ /wp-admin/admin.php?new=string [R,QSA,L]
```

As in your original code, this just checks for `key=value` in the query string, not `foo=bar&key=value` as in the source URL.

**UPDATE:** The second `RewriteCond` directive prevents a redirect loop by making sure that `new=string` is not already present at the start of the query string.

The `QSA` flag results in the query string on the request being appended to the substitution. So, the resulting URL will become `...?new=string&foo=bar&key=value`, not `?foo=bar&key=value&new=string` as in your initial requirement - is that a concern?

---

**UPDATE:** If you specifically need the `new=string` URL param *appended* to the query string then you should remove the `QSA` flag and use the `QUERY_STRING` server variable instead. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=value
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !new=string$
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/admin\.php$ /wp-admin/admin.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&new=string [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think this is close, but not quite. I would like to have the `new=string` appended at the end. But, with the `[R,QSA,L]` flag, the `new=string` query is repeated in the URL endlessly, and hence an error.

I tried `[R,L]` flag and use exact URL at the end of `RewriteRule`, that is `/wp-admin/admin.php?foo=bar&key=value&new=string [R,L]`. That gets me to the right URL, but ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS comes up. 

Any suggestion?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, an additional _condition_ is required to prevent a redirect loop. I've updated my answer and included an example of appending the URL param at the end of the query string, rather than at the start.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Never thought of the second condition. Thank you!